# Remove motd banner from Amazon AMI Linux 2023

Tags: motd

I'm trying to remove the motd banner in Amazon Linux AMI 2023

```
   ,     #_
   ~\_  ####_        Amazon Linux 2023
  ~~  \_#####\
  ~~     \###|
  ~~       \#/ ___   https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023
   ~~       V~' '->
    ~~~         /
      ~~._.   _/
         _/ _/
       _/m/'
```

I tried to look for these strings in /etc /var, but didn't find anything. It wasn't in the motd file.

Where could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff suggested, [[Bug] - motd resets when new AL2023 update is available #358](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/358) prompts a possible solution.

```bash
mkdir -p /etc/motd.d
touch /etc/motd.d/30-banner
```

Comment: You should be using https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/358#issuecomment-1564411668 instead. It's completely expected and normal that changes to files in `/usr` are reverted by the package manager - that directory is completely the domain of the package management system.

Comment: @muru You're right, but the comment there points to a wrong directory.